# submit form from file input box after selecting image

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, forms, file-upload

I am attempting to trigger a form submit from an input [type=file] dialog box window. I'm trying to streamline the process of selecting an image and then having to click another button to submit the form to the database.

I have updated the question to include screenshots and code below to hopefully make the issue I'm having more clear.

**Note:**
It was asked why I don't add an id to the input button, but I can't, as the file input is invoked from the function, and as it's a windows process, I have no ability to add/change it.

Here's some code / pics to better illustrate the issue.

1 - The user clicks the change pic button to update their profile image. This button runs a shortcode [upload-user-profile-avatar].

[image: Change Pic Button]

2 - The shortcode triggers the standard input file open box window.

[image: Input type=file]

3 - After the user either double clicks a file, or single clicks a file and presses the open button, the form for the user profile avatar plugin is automatically submitted.

**Attempts:**
I originally started out using jQuery to attempt to attach to the form and submit it on click,

```
    jQuery('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        nameOfForm.submit();
    });
```

However I read in a SO post that someone else was attempting something similar, and jQuery wouldn't submit the form, so they had to switch to javascript, which I did (since jQuery wasn't submitting the form)...and I came up with this for testing purposes.

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName("update-user-profile-avatar");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'file') {
        console.log(inputs[i].value);
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

So this was helpful in so much that I could see that the open dialog window is grabbing the correct filename, but still, the form isn't getting submitted and I'm getting a `form.submit() is not a function`  error in the console.

So then I read that html form submissions can have a lot of weirdness about them, so try something along these lines.

```
jQuery('input[type=file]').change(function(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'file') {
            console.log(inputs[i].value);
            HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form);
        }
    }
});
```

which produced this error:

```
'submit' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.
```

So I think I'm spinning my wheels here. I sense this is doable, I'm just not using the right method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xckbj814/)

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
   $('form').submit()
})
```

Unfortunately for security purposes the browser isn't going to let you access the open window. However with the `.change()` method, it will trigger whatever function you'd like once the value of the input has changed. Whether they double click a file to select it, or click the file and "open" button.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes sense. I will give that a try and report back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  I have played around with the code and can have gotten a bit closer using this method.

var form = document.getElementsByClassName("update-user-profile-avatar");
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'file') {
         console.log(inputs[i].value);
   form.submit();
     }
 }
 

I can see in the console log that it's grabbing the file, but the form doesn't submit. =/

Comment: Instead of using a loop over each input looking for a file type, try giving your file input an ID, and use document.getElementById(). It seems like you aren't even using jQuery, but you tagged this in jQuery. If you can put all of your code in your original question so I can see it, I'd be glad to help you.

Comment: I have upadated the question to include both my experiments with jQuery and javascript (that's why I tagged it jQuery), as neither hasn't gotten me to a solution. I hope it's more clear, and thanks so much for your help! :)